# Javascript / Jquery selector ($) in a rails def

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, selector

I have the following code in an html.erb file. It works fine for that page. I want to move it into a def in the application controller. When I try to do that, the $ shows as an unexpected bad character.

Is there a way to move this code to a def?

```
<!-- --------------   Begin Dirty Form Checker   -->

<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.are-you-sure.js" %>
<%= content_for(:body_attributes) do %> data-no-turbolink <% end %>

<script>
    var do_on_load = function() {
        $('form').areYouSure( {'silent':false} );
        $('form').areYouSure();
    }
    $(document).ready(do_on_load)
    $(window).bind('page:change', do_on_load)
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean that when you put the javascript code into `application_controller.rb` it is giving you an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just wrong. You don't place javascript in your ApplicationController. Javascript in Rails is a view concern and best practice is to avoid as far as possible ever mixing Ruby (or any other server side language) and Javascript*.

You place your javascript in external files (`app/assets/javascripts/*.js`). Instead of thinking of your scripts on a per page basis think of javascript as an extendable set of behaviors that you can add to elements in your app.

Use [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) or `data-*` attributes to target elements, and data attributes and JSON to pass data between client side and server side.

```
// app/assets/javascripts/supa_form.js
$(document).on('page:change', function(){
  $('.supa-form').submit(function(){
    if (!window.confirm('Are you sure?')) {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

### Why?

- Allows javascripts to be compiled and minimized at deploy time.
- Allows javascripts to be effectively cached.
- Allows javascripts to be tested independently of the rails application.
- Newbies who mix javascript and server side rendering get confused about what happens when and where.
- Avoids mixing data and logic.

Additional reading:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html
- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html